# Raspberry Pi 4: PermitRootLogin is set to "yes", but can't login with root

Tags: 19.10, raspberrypi, openssh

I just installed Ubuntu for Raspberry 19.10 on my Raspberry Pi 4.
I set `PermitRootLogin` to `yes`, but I can't login directly with root. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've got only Pi 3 (now with Raspbian 10) and some other machines with Ubuntu 18.

But I have just tested what are you are writing about. Everything is working as expected. And I can login with the root account.
So.. mb this will help.

What type of authentication do you want to use (pubkey vs password, etc)?
Just set-up keys (and directories' permissions) or password.
Enable `PubkeyAuthentication` or `PasswordAuthentication` in `sshd_config`.
Set `PermitRootLogin` (`yes` or without-password) and reload the `ssh` daemon.

Don't forget to check `pam` (`pam.d` directory - `ssh`, login) ecosystem if used.
There can be also active restrictions.

And try to login once again ;)

If this doesn't help, check the logs (also `/etc/securetty`).

Comment: While logging in with ssh use multiple -v switches: -vvvvv
You will get nice debug log directly from ssh.
On the server side just increase log verbosity to DEBUG.

Comment: I set PasswordAuthentification to yes and i disabled pam in sshd_config. Still no results..

Comment: Send us the debug/verbose log , what distribution do you exactly use? Ubuntu Core , Ubuntu Server for Pi? Send us pls output of: lsb_release -a

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are changing  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` not  `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: this is already mentioned in another answer